# How to add http method into Resource of Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, restful-url

I want keycloak protect my Restful URL, eg: `POST /user/1`, `DELETE /user/1`.
When I create a new resource in Keycloak, I found there are ONLY uris , but no HTTP method exists.
So how can I distinguish between DELETE and POST.

Answer (score 2):

[Keycloak Gatekeeper](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_keycloak_generic_adapter) has concept of resources, where you can define also authorization on the request method level, e.g.:

```
resources:
- uri: /*
- uri: /users/*
  methods:
  - GET
  roles:
  - viewer
- uri: /users/*
  methods:
  - POST
  - DELETE
  roles:
  - editor
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a possible solution using Authorization Scopes. You can create GET, POST, DELETE authorization scopes and associate them with your resource and then create scope base permission. For example when integrating with Spring Boot you just provide this setting in application.properties:

```
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.http-method-as-scope=true
```